# How could I create many radio inputs with for loop?

Tags: python, html, django

Here's my code:

```
{% for answer in value %}

                    <div class="answer">
                         <input type="radio" name="answer-checkbox" value="{{ answer.id }}">
                         {{ answer }}
                    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to create multiple sets of questions and answers, within each set only one answer could be selected at a time, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `value` is an object list, and for each object `answer` there is `answer.id` representing the answer you use, and `answer.label` you use for display.

try the following:

```
<div class="answer">
{% for answer in value %}
  <input type="radio" id="{{ answer.id }}" name="answer-checkbox" value="{{  answer.id }}">
  <label for={{  answer.id }}>{{ answer.label }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Good Luck